# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "day": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I would want to remove data from sqlite x days from now
my device_time column is milliseconds.

```
DELETE FROM aalast_update WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',  device_time/ 1000, 'unixepoch') <= datetime('now' , -60 day)
```

Is there something im missing? Or is there any other way Im not seeing from the docs?

Comment: If it doesn't work it isn't correct.

Comment: Try to put the final parameter into a string, and write "days", plural: `<= datetime('now' , '-60 days')`. This from the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) which shows this example: `SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');`.

Comment: aww, from your example I was reminded of the single quote. Ah I missed that. thanks anyway